# how to print month on calendar with list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

basically need to print a calendar for a month using list comprehension.

cant figure out how to make this work, if anyone can help itd be greatly appreciated

not great with list comprehension so not sure where to even start with this

Comment: Please show an example of desired output, and any attempt you have made so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html) library to display a calendar in a variety of formats

```
>>> calendar.monthcalendar(2022, 12)
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
 [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
 [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
 [26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 0]]

>>> calendar.TextCalendar().prmonth(2022, 12)
   December 2022
Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa Su
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27 28 29 30 31
```

To produce the format in your example you can use a list comprehension to convert the nested list of `int` to your padded strings

```
>>> [['{:02d}'.format(day) if day != 0 else '' for day in week] for week in calendar.monthcalendar(2022, 12)]
[['', '', '', '01', '02', '03', '04'],
 ['05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11'],
 ['12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18'],
 ['19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25'],
 ['26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '']]
```